# Upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro, Cannot Dismiss Backup Notification

Tags: windows-backup, windows-8.1, action-center

I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 via the Windows Store. To my dismay, the Windows 7 File Recovery tool has been removed. OK, whatever, I can find something else to fulfill my needs. However, there is a notification stuck in both the tray and in the Action Center. I have no clue how to dismiss it. See screenshots below. Clicking on the notifications does nothing. Clicking `Options` does nothing either.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I hope this isn't true...

Comment: Hope what isn't true? My problem or the Windows 7 File Recovery being removed?

Comment: What do you see when you click options?

Comment: Technically the Windows 7 Backup Tool was discontinued in Windows 8.0, granted I will give you the following, Microsoft did a horrible job notifying users of that fact.

Comment: @JustinSkiles well the fact that it was removed, I used it... a lot...